# Is the cause of green emission in ZnO still unknown?

Tags: visible-light, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, photon-emission

I know that many researchers ascribe this emission to oxygen vacancy, but I also read some convincing articles that negate this conclusion. Is the source still a matter of controversy? I think so, but it's always good to check.